# php artisan serve does not allow change .env file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I found the problem

> if i restart `php artisan serve` the changed values are applied. this is
>   the norm? how can i solve this

I created a router where I output config information

[image: dd config]

I'm trying to change value from .env file, for example `APP_NAME`, from `APP_NAME="Nuxt + Laravel"` to `APP_NAME="test"` but the change is not displayed on the page!(of course I reloaded the page )

I was trying to look through `php artisan tinker`
[image: tinker]

It works! 
But my config remains the same. I can not solve this problem for a week now.

**I cleared the cache!!!** I tried `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` (i tried all command for cache)

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

I deleted files `bootsprap/cache/*`, `storage/framework/cache/*`.

**I tried everything!!!**

I have this project on the github: https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-nuxt.
Please help me, I want my project to be used by other people.

Comment: screens from local machine or server?

Comment: first screen - my browser(dd function), second - my local git bash console

Comment: did you try `php artisan view:clear` ?

Comment: tinker not cached, i think in env APP_NAME=Nuxt + Laravel

Comment: i tried all command for cache. my APP_NAME="test". I tried many times to clone the repository and there the error was repeated

Comment: if i do `php artisan config:cache` - my config will change as it should

Comment: hooray, I found the source of the problem, if i restart `php artisan serve` the changed values are applied. this is the norm? how can i solve this